# C++ cannot call method (with template) from within templated method

Tags: c++, templates, methods

I've got the following method within a header file called 'filter.h':

```
namespace std{

//some code

template <class T, class S, class BorderMethod>
tImage<T> binomial(const tImage<T> &in, const size_t k = 3) {
   //do some computations

  tImage<T> img = in.convolve<T, BorderMethod>(in, kernel);
  return img;
}
}
```

First thing I've noticed: the definition of this method takes place within the header-file. Is that standard procedure?

Now, the actual problem: The call to the method `convolve` won't work, even though `in` does possess such a method. Here's the definition of the method `convolve` within the class `tImage<T>`:

```
tImage<T> convolve(const gravis::tImage<T>& image, const gravis::tArray<typename tImageTraits<T>::Float_t>& kernel);
```

How do I have to call this function?

Comment: `in` is `const` argument, so a non-`const` member function cannot be invoked upon it.

Comment: `binomial` seems to think `convolve` is a function template, but `convolve` doesn't look like a function template (just a member function of a template class).

Comment: Why is your code in `namespace std`? It's illegal to add to the `std` namespace (other than specializations).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> First thing I've noticed: the definition of this method takes place within the header-file. Is that standard procedure?

Yes. Normally the definitions of function templates are put in headers. If they were relegated in a separate `.cpp` file, the compiler wouldn't be able to instantiate them implicitly when invoked, and unless you take proper action this will result in the linker complaining about undefined references. See [this Q&A on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) for more information.

> The call to the method convolve won't work, even though in does possess such a method.

`convolve()` is a non-`const` member function, and you are trying to invoke it through a reference to `const`. This is illegal and the compiler is telling you that.

---

Moreover, as correctly pointed out by [JBentley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1227469/jbentley) in his answer, you cannot add new declarations or definitions to the `std` namespace. Per Paragraph 17.6.4.2.1/1 of the C++11 Standard:

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a
>   namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified. [...]

Comment: Thank you! I called the namespace `std` because of lack of another name for this specific question ... but still, I wasn't aware of the fact, that I can't name my own namespace `std`, so thanks for that anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Although not the cause of your problem, your code has undefined behaviour because you have illegally placed it inside the `std` namespace.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320798/adding-types-to-the-std-namespace) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683794/bad-practice-to-declare-names-in-the-standard-namespace).